# What is the limit of file size in ftruncate in OSX?

Tags: c, macos, truncate, macos-mojave

I am trying to call `ftruncate` in OSX (10.14.5) and (10.14.4) as below:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    off_t len;
    FILE *fp;
    int ret;
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Usage:\n$0 filename length\n" );
        exit(-1);
    }
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "a+");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open %s: %s\n",
                    argv[1], strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }
    len = (off_t) atoll(argv[2]);
    uint64_t m = 1ULL << len;
    printf("%lld\n", m/(1024*1024*1024));
    errno = 0;
    ret = ftruncate(fileno(fp), m);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't truncate(\"%s\",%llu): %s\n",
                 argv[1], len, strerror(errno));
    }
    fclose(fp);
    exit(ret);
}
```

I have 100G left in the filesystem. The issue is that `ftruncate` succeeds with values that I do not understand, and fails with values I do not understand.
I get surprising values, sometimes failing and succeeding for same size. Here is a typical run on a machine with OSX (10.14.4).

```
| ./alloc x 42
4096.000000
Couldn't truncate("x",42): No space left on device
| ./alloc x 41
2048.000000
| ./alloc x 42
4096.000000
| du -sh x    
4.0T    x
| rm x        
| ./alloc x 42
4096.000000
Couldn't truncate("x",42): No space left on device
| du -sh x    
  0B    x
| ./alloc x 42
4096.000000
Couldn't truncate("x",42): No space left on device
| du -sh x    
  0B    x
| ./alloc x 41
2048.000000
| du -sh x    
2.0T    x
| ./alloc x 40
1024.000000
| du -sh x    
  0B    x
```

On another with OSX (10.14.5) I do not see the size after creation at all, with similarly surprising values, sometimes failing and succeeding for same size.

```
| ./alloc x 41
2048.000000
Couldn't truncate("x",41): No space left on device
zsh: exit 255   ./alloc x 41
| ./alloc x 40
1024.000000
| du -sh x
  0B    x
| rm x
| ./alloc x 40
1024.000000
Couldn't truncate("x",40): No space left on device
zsh: exit 255   ./alloc x 40
| du -sh x
  0B    x
| ./alloc x 39
512.000000
| du -sh x
  0B    x
```

What is happening here? and what is the actual limit for `ftruncate` in OSX?

Note that unlike in the linked answer, I am not asking whether `ftruncate` actually copies data. My question is why there are so different results in different consecutive runs, and specifically in the OSX machines I have it seems to behave differently in both machines. If it is not related to the filesystem, why does it fail on somewhat different values in different systems?

Comment: A couple of unrelated things: First why are you using the floating-point `powl` function? Some quick bit-manipulation and shifting would be enough. Then why are you continuing to use floating-point arithmetic in `m/(1024.0*1024.0*1024.0)`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am not an expert in C. If you can provide the correct way, I am happy to fix the program.

Comment: `1ULL << 42` should do it!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks. Did I convince you that this is not a duplicate question? Neither the question nor the answers there seem to be same as mine. Specifically, it fails and succeeds with `42` sometimes, in one machine while it fails and succeeds with `40` in another.